# adding nested ul list from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

there. I have a ul on a webpage that I'm populating from the behind code with a database I have organized in a tree. I can get the values from the db just fine and list them altogether, but the child nodes i would like to appear in an inner list under each parent. Here's my current behind code

```
    protected void createMenu(TreeView navTree) {

        foreach(TreeNode node in navTree.Nodes){

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        navMenu.Controls.Add(li);

        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "toggle");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("onClick", "navButton");
        anchor.InnerText = node.Text;

        li.Controls.Add(anchor);


        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) {

            HtmlGenericControl child_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            navMenu.Controls.Add(child_li);

            HtmlGenericControl childAnchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            childAnchor.Attributes.Add("href", "");
            childAnchor.Attributes.Add("onClick", "childButton");
            childAnchor.InnerText = childNode.Text;

            child_li.Controls.Add(childAnchor);
        }

        }

    }
```

and here's the html I'm trying to recreate:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<nav>
  <h2>Sites</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="toggle"><a href="#">Akron</a></li>
    <li class="toggle"><a href="#">Monterey</a></li>
    <li class="toggle is-open"><a href="#">Sacramento</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#"><span class="quantity">5</span> George</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="quantity">7</span> John</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="quantity">18</span> Bob</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle"><a href="#">Stanislaus</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, you need to create a sub <ul> tag.

```
 foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) {
            HtmlGenericControl child_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            navMenu.Controls.Add(child_li);
```

becomes

```
 if(node.ChildNodes.Count > 0) {
     HtmlGenericControl child_ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
     li.Controls.Add(child_ul);
     foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) {
            HtmlGenericControl child_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            child_ul.Controls.Add(child_li);
```

etc...

Comment: thanks! I figured it out. I also added an onclick event with   anchor.Attributes.Add("onClick", "navButtonClick"); and a simple js function for it that does an alert, but it doesnt seem to  be firing. Is there something special I need to do since i made the list dynamically?

Comment: @WillTuttle Sounds like a JS only event?  Try putting alert where navButtonClick is now first.  Once that works, try putting `()` on the end of the function name.